# Remove unused CSS classes from frameworks like bootstrap in a react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

We are currently developing a react project using webpack and babel and would like to have automatically removed unused CSS classes in the CSS frameworks Bootstrap and AdminLTE 2 which we use.

In the project we use **webpack (v4.41.0)**, **babel (v7.6.2)** and **react (16.10.1)**. To use CSS classes we are using the babel plugin **babel-plugin-react-css-modules** which uses css modules.

What is a modern and contemporary way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss-webpack-plugin

Comment: @djfdev I have already looked at **purgecss** and **purifycss** and am not so sure if they work properly in combination with **babel-plugin-react-css-modules**. Also, purifycss had the last commit on March 18, 2018.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As djfdev already wrote purgecss works quite well: purgcss simply searches all JavaScript files for occurrences of the [CSS class strings](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/blob/master/src/Extractors/DefaultExtractor.js) of the used CSS files and removes those which cannot be found.

Comment: The link seems to be down

Comment: This regex is now inside this File: [https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/blob/master/packages/purgecss/src/options.ts#L6](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/blob/master/packages/purgecss/src/options.ts#L6)

Answer (score 0):

You should add these two configs:

```
defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
safelist: {
  standard: ["html", "body"],
},
```

to your postcss config. I am using [craco][1] and this is how the config file looks like:

```
const purgecss = require("@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss");

module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        purgecss({
          content: ["./src/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.js"],
          css: ["./src/**/*.css"],
          defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
          safelist: {
            standard: ["html", "body"],
          },
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

If you are using postcss config it should look the same.
[1]: https://purgecss.com/guides/react.html#use-craco